# Ionic Capacitor (Angular): how to prevent closing of keyboard after "submit" with enter key

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

In Ionic Capacitor (I am using Angular): How do I keep displaying the keyboard open, prevent it from closing, when the user submits the form or input?

I know there are questions like this one on StackOverflow, but they refer to Ionic Cordova and not Ionic Capacitor.

I want this to work on native IOS/Android, I don't care about PWA. (and dont care about Desktop-Web of course, since it doesnt even have a keyboard on the screen).

Comment: Did you try `event.preventDefault()` and/or returning `false` from your submit handler function?

Comment: returning false from the submit handler function solved it

Comment: I posted this also as an answer so you can accept it and by doing that mark your question as answered. It is good practice to close questions/issues that are answered/resolved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `event.preventDefault()` and/or returning `false` from your submit handler function? These are usually the "tricks" to prevent such things (like keyboard closing) from happening.

Answer (score 0):

This code should keep the keyboard open and maintain focus on the IonTextarea when you submit the form

```
@ViewChild('textarea') private readonly textarea: IonTextarea;


onSubmit(ev) {
  this.textarea.setFocus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is typically controlled by the mobile operating system and not the web application.

You might want to manually control the keyboard visibility using the Capacitor Keyboard API. Here's an example of how you can keep the keyboard open:

```js
import { Keyboard } from '@capacitor/keyboard';

// After form submit
Keyboard.setAccessoryBarVisible({ isVisible: true });
```

Comment: This method is only supported on iPhone devices.